# ASP.NET MVC : Create an ambient value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, viewstate

I have a simple web-site. Almost every action takes `int toonId` as an argument (toonId does not equate to the user: one user can own multiple toons).
At the moment I provide that value to every view from controller, and every link and submit button sends this value back to the controller.
This works. I am just looking for an easier way to accomplish this (AOP comes to mind).

I use cookies to persist "favorite/default toon", and this works fine (used with ActionAttribute, that takes toonId from cookie and passes is to the toonId argument, if toonId wasn't provided). But I want to support cookie-less sessions as well.

**Question**: What is an easy way to add ambient variable to the page, without passing it explicitly all over? Such that it would work with cookie-less browsers.

Is Viewstate a way to go (which isn't supposed to be in the MVC)?
Is server-side session a way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what session is meant for.

There is no page lifecycle in asp.net mvc, hence no viewstate.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can automatically pass query string parameters for use cookie-less browsers if you plug in your own implementation of `IRouteHandler`.  I have not tried it though.  I found [an example](http://flux88.com/blog/excerpt-from-asp-net-mvc-in-action-chapter-6/) of implementing `IRouteHandler` although it does not show how to implement the query string parameter functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on what 'toonid' represents.  If it's 'ambient per user session', then as womp stated, Session state would work well for this.  However, if it's somethign that has a larger scope (e.g. a colleciton of toonids that are commonly accessed by all users) then teh Cache would be a better and more scalable strategy.